# Did Eddie Morra kill the blind third person?

Tags: plot-explanation, limitless

In *Limitless* Eddie morra wanted to give NZT to a thug. He was out of it. In the fight he killed two persons but not the third one. What happened to the third?

Answer (score 1):

Eddie kills the mob boss and drinks his blood, stabs a mobster who has a white eye in his another eye; and this eyesight impaired mobster shoots and kills the second mobster.

Eddie escapes his penthouse after he pushes a piano onto the shooting mobster, aka the 3rd person.

- I do not think the movie has explicitly stated whether the third mobster has been killed or just knocked unconscious. Largely due to the fact that the 3rd person / mobster is a minor character.